# Add new column based on multiple conditions of letters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame df and I want to do subset based on several conditions of letters of the names in Command.

1. if the names contain PD
2. if the names contain t1
3. if the names contain t2
4. if the names contain t1 and PD
5. if the names contain t2 and PD
6. otherwise the names would be unknown

I want these subsets as the colors for my plot. I don't know how to use grep for all these conditions. Here is my current df:

```
'data.frame': 36919 obs. of 162 variables
$TE                :int 38,41,11,52,48,75,.....
$TR                :int 100,210,548,546,.....
$Command          :factor W/2229 levels "_localize_PD","_localize_tre_t2","_abdomen_t1_seq","knee_pd_t1_localize"...
```

but I want the output of my subsets to produce a new column like this:

```
$TE                :int 38,41,11,52,48,75,.....
$TR                :int 100,210,548,546,.....
$NewCommand           :factor W/6 levels "PD","t2","t1","t1+PD",...
```

I used the following to get the first 3 subsets:

```
hast1=grepl("t1", df$Command)
hast2=grepl("t2", df$Command)
haspd=grepl("pd", df$Command)
```

Now I don't know how to get the other 3 subsets and use these 6 subsets as colors of my plot.
thanks for any help.

Comment: @ch-elahe please post what your tried in your question, rather than in the comments section. It makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: I have tried what is mentioned in the post, do you have any idea? @Imo

Comment: @ch-elahe The outcome that you are intending is unclear, and the infor you have provided regarding your dataset is limited. When you post, at a minimum, add a text based version of what your dataset looks like and a text based version of what you want it to look like. See the following tips on producing a [minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ch-elahe For example, do you really want to drop observations (ie subset your data)? If your intent is to produce a graph with each of the 6 categories having different colors, then what you actually want is to create a new variable that indicates these categories. This is why providing an example of the desired output is always requested.

Comment: @Imo  you were right and now I added my desired output.thanks for your comment

Comment: so you want to strip everything from `df$command` except those specified in conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract specific strings and replace with `NA` when patterns not found, then probably this will do it.

First create a vector with conditions, and use `str_extract` from `stringr` to return the patterns. If a pattern is not found, then it will return `NA`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- c('PD', 't1', 't2', 't1+PD', 't2+PD')
str_extract(df$command, paste(v1, collapse='|'))
```

Comment: @ Sotos the 'str_extract ' is close to what I want but I want all the NAs to be replaced by 'unkonwn', there's also other problem that using ggplot(df,aes(x=TE,y=TR,color=Protocol))+geom_point() does not give me a plot with my subsets do you know what's the reason?

Answer (score 0):

the correct way of getting names with multiple conditions is:

```
hasPDT2 =grepl("(.*t2.*PD.*)|(.*PD.*t2.*)", df$Command)
hasPDT1 =grepl("(.*t1.*PD.*)|(.*PD.*t1.*)", df$Command)
```

and then we can create a new column to contain these new names:

```
df$new_name = NA
df[haspd,'new_name'] = 'pd'
df[hast1,'new_name'] = 't1'
df[hast2,'new_name'] = 't2'
df[hasPDT2,'new_name'] = 'pdt2'
df[hasPDT1,'new_name'] = 'pdt1'
```

the order of these commands is important